# How to replace with unique id

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying something like this:

```
var paragraphy= "Lorem ipsum dolar amet. Lorem ipsum dolar amet."
var uniqueid=Math.random().toString( 16 ).slice( 2, 10 );
paragraphy.replace(/dolar/gi,'<span id="'+uniqueid+'"'>$1</span>);
```

Result:

```
... <span id='ce79657a'>dolar</span>... ipsum <span id='ce79657a'>dolar</span> ...
```

but I want as this result:

```
... <span id='ce79657a'>dolar</span>... ipsum <span id='ad45234f'>dolar</span> ...
```

How can I do that? Thanks for help.

Comment: Maybe [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/11np293g/) can help. Calculate that random ID inside the replace callback.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Why replace this "<, >" if i use replace span element show as string. If i don't use  nested span on dom.

Comment: It is only for demo. You would not see the span tag otherwise.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew thanks you for your advice and solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with [`replace()` callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

```js
var paragraphy = "Lorem ipsum dolar amet. Lorem ipsum dolar amet."

paragraphy = paragraphy.replace(/dolar/gi, function(m) {
  var uniqueid = Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 10);
  return '<span id="' + uniqueid + '">' + m + '</span>'
});

console.log(paragraphy);
```